# Get first and last calendar day of the year

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I'm looking for a way to get the first and the last calendar day in french locale for a given year on Oracle.

For example, the first calendar day of 2020 is 30/12/2019 (because its the monday of week 1 of 2020) and the last calendar day is 03/01/2021 (because its the sunday of week 53 of 2020).

I got plenty of solutions for 01/01/2020 and 31/12/2020 but not for the calendar first and last day.

I tried with to_date with `select trunc(to_date('1 2020','IW YYYY'), 'YEAR') from dual;` but got ORA-01820 error code.
with `select to_date('1 2020','DDD YYYY') from dual;` i got 01/01/20 00:00:00

Thanks you for help.

Comment: My calendar starts from `Sun` Europe time. Does it fits your wall?

Answer (score 3):

You could do:

```
select 
    trunc(date'2020-01-01', 'IW') first_calendar_day_2020, 
    trunc(date'2020-12-31', 'IW') + 6 last_calendar_day_2020
from dual
```

`IW` gives you the first day of the ISO week for the corresponding date. If you want the sunday of that week, you can just add 6 days.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e4de1e8be423d1818813f072ebe42328)**:

```
FIRST_CALENDAR_DAY_2020 | LAST_CALENDAR_DAY_2020
:---------------------- | :---------------------
30-DEC-19               | 03-JAN-21
```

Comment: Very good you mention that first day of week may fall into previous year.

Comment: Should the second column be `last_calendar_day_2021`?

Comment: There is 2 problèmes with your solution :
1) you have to write yourself the first day and last day of year into the request instead of the number of the year. i would prefer have the first and last calendar day for a given year or a given date, ie i give a column value from a table and i can get 2 columns corresponding to the first and last calendar day
2) it does not work for 2021, your solution give 28/12/2020 instead of 04/01/2021 (28/12/2020 is the start of week 53 of 2020)